# How do I move a Bootstrap input group to the top of a text field?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to move this add-on to the top of the text box, but I don't see an easy way to do it without breaking the design.

[image]

Here is my current code:

```
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon redbar">Some long<br>addon text here:</span>
        <input type="text"
               name="someName"
               maxlength="11"
               style="height:134%;"
               class="form-control"
               title="some title"
               placeholder="the content"/>
</div>
```

(Adding the line break and adjusting the height was my band-aid solution.) I understand that I can use a label, but doing so would make it inconsistent with the rest of the site (unless it's somehow styled the same).

I tried looking at various SO posts, but didn't see anything relevant.  Is this possible with Bootstrap?

Comment: What is going on with your markup? Is that valid HTML?

Comment: ha ha, yes - Spring has a form tag liibrary.  Spring also uses the `path` attribute

Comment: Spring? I'm guessing that's a framework, in which case you're best to announce that before anyone else thinks you've coded incorrectly.

Comment: Ok, removed those references

Comment: No, that's not what I meant. Because now you have invalid HTML. I meant to state what you are using.

Comment: What about it is invalid?  My IDE isn't catching anything wrong with that HTML

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107255/discussion-between-bphilipnyc-and-lee).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure on how you want it to be displayed. If you can show an image of how you want it then we can surely come up with exact solution. However, I have put on [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f9feamb2/) that might me in your track I guess.

```css
.redbar{
 text-align: center;
border-image: none;
border-radius: 3px !important;
border-left: 3px solid red !important;
border-right: 3px solid red !important;
display: block !important;
width: 150px !important;
margin: 0px auto;
  float: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon redbar">Some long<br>addon text here:</span>
        <input type="text"
               name="someName"
               maxlength="11"
               style="height:134%;"
               class="form-control"
               title="some title"
               placeholder="the content"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="input-group">
<div class="col-xs-12 redbar">Some long<br>addon text here:</div>
<input type="text" 
     name="someName" 
     maxlength="11" 
     style="height:134%;" 
     class="form-control" 
     title="some title"
     placeholder="the content"/>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.redbar{
  text-align:center;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f9feamb2/

I think this is the result you needed.
Removed the class .input-group-addon

Comment: did you mean to close the second div?

Comment: " <span class="input-group-addon redbar">Some long<br>addon text here:</span>  "

Change above span to div 
Span will have inbuilt property of display:inline-block.
If you use div it will automatically break into another line

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, please go with the edited answer 
https://jsfiddle.net/f9feamb2/

Comment: Okey now i had updated the js fiddle with add-on portion and red border.

Comment: Hmm - I don't see it on the fiddle.  If you're using the add-on, the background of the top portion should be gray